# No module named matplotlib after install

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to using matplotlib with no luck.

To install I typed

```
pip install matplotlib
```

after install I checked pip list and matplotlib is in the list vers. 2.0.2

Then I try to import it with

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

and I get the error "No module named matplotlib"

I am completely at a loss any help would be appreciated.

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong in the question it is spelled correctly in the python file

Comment: is it installed globally or in your virtualenv? if it is in your virtualenv have you activated the virtualenv?

Comment: I have no idea why but removing sudo when calling the script works

Comment: Please provide the outputs of these commands  1. `which python`  2.  `which pip`  3. `head -1 $(which pip)`

Comment: if you feel the answer is right please upvote it and accept it as the correct answer

Comment: which python /usr/bin/python
which pip /usr/bin/pip
head -1 $(which pip)  #!/usr/bin/python

Comment: all looks fine.  maybe you used sudo somewhere, don't do that, it screws up permissions.  instead use `pip install --user matplotlib`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue now and was resolved by:

1. `pip uninstall matplotlib`
2. `sudo apt-get install python-matplotlib`

Comment: you should accept answers and vote them if you think it helped. Ethics of the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing matplotlib via anaconda distribution.

```
conda install matplotlib
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue while working a DL course, the issue was actually with numpy on Windows 10. You can try downgrading the numpy version or use anaconda